# Posting to PHP using AJAX - Returning full PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

The issue I'm having is that when I'm attempting to post to a PHP page it will just return the entire PHP document and not the things being echoed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ type:"POST",
             url:"backMap/locationCreation.php",
             data: { name: "TEMP" },
             success: function(data) { $("#awesomet").html(data);},
             error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data) {
                alert("Error: " + thrownError); 
             }
    });
 </script>
 <div id="awesomet">Not showing.</div>
```

With this I am trying to send an Ajax Post to the given URL.  I am giving it some data and if it returns successfully then it will put it's data within the div.

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
       echo "Asked for name!";
   }
   for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
      echo '<p>For loop! Value: ' . $i . ' of 10.</p>';
   }
 ?>
```

When I call this I receive the entire php page as a result.

I literally get the whole page, if statements, for loop and all.  Including the `<?php` flags.  I don't understand why I'm receiving the data like this.

I am running this through Phonegap.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You still need to have PHP module loaded. http://phonegap.com/about/faq/ Read the last question

Comment: So I assume that means the only way you can make a post to a php page is using something like xmlhttp?

Comment: for starters I think you need to change it to isset($_POST['name'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the entire php file including the PHP declaration, this might point to a problem with your webserver configuration. Maybe your webserver does not recognize files ending on .php as PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ type:"POST",
             url:"backMap/locationCreation.php",
             data: { name: "TEMP" },
             dataType : 'json',
             success: function(data) { $("#awesomet").html(data.return);},
             error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data.return) {
                alert("Error: " + thrownError); 
             }
    });
 </script>
```

And in the php

```
 if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $a =array();
   $a['return'] = "Asked for name!";
   echo json_encode($a);
 }
```

Also, you have to check your Apache configuration, because you are getting somehow the .php file